# Output SQL Results as Table in Email

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email, powershell

I've put together a powershell script that queries a SQL database for items within a specific date range and emails out the list (four columns of data) if there are any results returned. The script itself functions perfectly now, but I'm trying to figure out how to nicely format the results in the email, using plain text.

In Powershell, it's easy enough to use | format-table -autosize with the results and display them in PS, but the only way I've managed to get the results into the email is with out-string, and no matter how I try to format it, they're just kind of a jumbled mess. Is there a good way to clean this up?

The line I'm using to generate the email body is:

```
$msg.body = "Here are the items that need to be returned in the next 30 days:"+"`n"+$results | out-string
```

EDIT: More code (the entire function I'm using to generate/send the email), per request:

```
function sendMail{
 Write-Host "Sending Email"
 #SMTP server name
 $smtpServer = "mailserver"
 #Creating a Mail object
 $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
 #Creating SMTP server object
 $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
 #Email structure 
 $msg.From = "me@company.com"  #****Change Message Sender
 $msg.To.Add("every1else@company.com") #***Add Recipients 
 $msg.subject = "Lease Returns in Next 30 Days"  #***Change subject
 $msg.body = "Here are the items that need to be returned in the next 30 days:"+"`n"+$results | out-string
 #Sending email 
 $smtp.Send($msg)
 }
```

Comment: what kind of email? html? plain text? if you want a nicely formatted email, then you should generate a mime email with an embedded html table. if you're just stuffing spaces/tabs and linebreaks into some text, the mail client is free to display that however it wants.

Comment: Can you post some more code?

Comment: I was hoping I could get away with plain text, but I'm realizing that's just silly.

Answer (score 1):

Why use powershell? Why not sql if you are quering a sql database.
As long as you know the query you want to run, and you have Database Mail configured, lovely description at this MSDN blog on how to do it: [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlagent/archive/2010/11/03/sql-database-mail-send-t-sql-results-by-email.aspx)

If you need to know how to setup Database Mail: [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245116.aspx) or [Link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/)